# My web app cannot find my any of my files.

Tags: filepath

My web application is inside of a folder called application and inside my index.html I am providing the project path to the css file, but it gives me a 404 not found. Any ideas?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="application/css/style.css">
```

css folder and file style.css both exist and the css folder is located inside of application. This happens to all my files.

Comment: Can you link the actual folder structure?  My guess is you don't need "application," and changing it to 'href="css/style.css"' would probably work, but it's just speculation.

Comment: Yes that worked, but why woudn't I need application

Comment: application/css/style.css would only work if you had a folder called "application" inside of the "application" folder you mentioned in your question. The paths would be relative to your `index.html` file.